# How to concatenate row and column to a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel

I need concatenate cell = row&column in Excel table like that:

```
        a   b   c

1       a1  b1  c1

2       a2  b2  c2

3       a3  b3  c3
```

But when I select 4 first conner cell and drag-copy. It not work as I expected.
What I need to do?

Comment: You mean cell=column&row right, not the other way around

Comment: Yes.Always like that because I have so many rows and columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

See the attached image for solution. You need to freeze the row using a $.

Comment: Thanks! Work Ok column by column. It's big table and I want match all cell(look row + look column)

Comment: You need to use `=B$1&$A1` - use the `$` to lock any row or column, i.e. `$A1` keeps the `A`, `A$1` keeps the `1` and `$A$1` keeps both!

Comment: Thanks!Simple and Quick!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting numbers for your columns instead of rows then you need to use a User Defined Function to convert the Columns into letters.

You can use this one from the Microsoft site (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833402):

```
Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```

Then you simply need to adjust your formula to:

```
=ConvertToLetter(COLUMN())&ROW()
```

You might also want to check the `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS` functions (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213933) and (http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/address-function-HP010062407.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience about VB.Maybe I will learn. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No worries, still not sure it's what you're after but check this page out they're very easy to get started with and very powerful. http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2007-HA010218996.aspx. Good luck.